# -1073741819 (0xC0000005) program termination in C and how not to use pointers

Tags: c, pointers

[image]Haven't used C in a while and get -1073741819 (0xC0000005) after I ask a user for the d, m, y inputs. I assume it's something to do with how I use pointers. I have created a different program using the pointers similarly, and it all worked fine and dandy. Don't really know what else to say. Why would the program not work. I feel like it's something ridiculously obvious and stupid, but I just can't see it. :D

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void date (int *d, int *m, int *y);
void name (char vards[20], char uzvards[20]);
void income (float *ienakums);
void writefile(int *y,int *m, int *d, char vards[20],char uzvards[20],float *ienakums);


int main(void) {

 char Name[20], last[20];
 int diena,menesis,gads;
 float cash;

    // step 1 - get name + check
    name(&Name[20], &last[20]);
    // step 2 - get date + check
    date(&diena,&menesis,&gads);
    // step 3 - get income + check
    income(&cash);
    // step 4 - write the file
    writefile(&gads,&menesis,&diena,&Name[20],&last[20],&cash);




    }
void name(char vards[20], char uzvards[20]){

int check = 1;
int counter = 0;

do{
    printf("Ievadiet jusu vardu\n");
    gets(vards);

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(vards); i++)
    {
      if(isdigit(vards[i]) > 0)
      {
          counter++;
      }

    }
    if(counter == 0)
    {
        check = 0;
    }
    else{

        check = 1;
    }
}while(check == 1);

check = 0;
do{
    printf("Ievadiet jusu uzvardu\n");
    gets(uzvards);

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(vards); i++)
    {
      if(isdigit(vards[i]) > 0)
      {
          counter++;
      }

    }
    if(counter == 0)
    {
        check = 0;
    }
    else{

        check = 1;
    }
}while(check == 1);
    printf("\nJusu vards ir %s %s",vards,uzvards);


}

void date (int *d, int *m, int *y){

*d = 0;
*m = 0;
*y = 0;

do{
    printf("\nLudzu ievadiet jusu dzimsanas dienu: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &d);

}while((d<=0) || (d>31));

do{
    printf("\nLudzu ievadiet jusu dzimsanas menesi: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &m);
}while((m<=0) || (m>12));

do{
    printf("\nLudzu ievadiet jusu dzimsanas gadu: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &y);

}while((y<1900) || (y>2021));

    printf("\n %d %d %d",*d,*m,*y);
}

void income (float *ienakums){

//do{
printf("\nIevadiet videjos ienakumus: ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%f", &ienakums);
//}while(isdigit(ienakums) <= 0);
    printf("%f",*ienakums);

}

void writefile(int *y,int *m, int *d, char vards[20],char uzvards[20],float *ienakums)
{
  FILE *file = fopen("dati.txt", "a+");
    fprintf(file, "\n\tVards:%s  Uzvards:%s  Dzimsanas Datums:%d %d %d Ienakums %.2f EUR \n", vards, uzvards, *d, *m, *y, *ienakums);
    fclose(file);
}
```

The code now looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void date (int *d, int *m, int *y);
void name (char vards[20], char uzvards[20]);
void income (float *ienakums);
void writefile(int *y,int *m, int *d, char vards[20],char uzvards[20],float *ienakums);


int main(void) {

 char Name[20], last[20];
 int diena,menesis,gads;
 float cash;

    // step 1 - get name + check
    name(Name, last);
    // step 2 - get date + check
    date(&diena,&menesis,&gads);
    // step 3 - get income + check
    income(&cash);
    // step 4 - write the file
    writefile(&gads,&menesis,&diena,Name,last,&cash);




    }
void name(char vards[20], char uzvards[20]){

int check = 1;
int counter = 0;

do{
    printf("Ievadiet jusu vardu\n");
    gets(vards);

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(vards); i++)
    {
      if(isdigit(vards[i]) > 0)
      {
          counter++;
      }

    }
    if(counter == 0)
    {
        check = 0;
    }
    else{

        check = 1;
    }
}while(check == 1);

check = 0;
do{
    printf("Ievadiet jusu uzvardu\n");
    gets(uzvards);

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(vards); i++)
    {
      if(isdigit(vards[i]) > 0)
      {
          counter++;
      }

    }
    if(counter == 0)
    {
        check = 0;
    }
    else{

        check = 1;
    }
}while(check == 1);
    printf("\nJusu vards ir %s %s",vards,uzvards);


}

void date (int *d, int *m, int *y){

*d = 0, *m = 0, *y =0;

do{
    printf("\nLudzu ievadiet jusu dzimsanas dienu: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", d);

}while((*d<=0) || (*d>31));

do{
    printf("\nLudzu ievadiet jusu dzimsanas menesi: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", m);
}while((*m<=0) || (*m>12));

do{
    printf("\nLudzu ievadiet jusu dzimsanas gadu: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", y);

}while((*y<1900) || (*y>2021));

    printf("\n %d %d %d",d,m,y);
}

void income (float *ienakums){

//do{
printf("\nIevadiet videjos ienakumus: ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%f", ienakums);
//}while(isdigit(ienakums) <= 0);
    printf("%f",ienakums);
}

void writefile(int *y,int *m, int *d, char vards[20],char uzvards[20],float *ienakums)
{
  FILE *file = fopen("dati.txt", "a+");
    fprintf(file, "\n\tVards:%s  Uzvards:%s  Dzimsanas Datums:%d %d %d Ienakums %.2f EUR \n", vards, uzvards, d, m, y, ienakums);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: `&Name[20]` is the address of the item one past the end of the array. Just use `name(Name, last);` Same in other places.

Comment: Please choose a title which is useful for others with the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: Also, there's no need to pass the address of a variable unless you plan on changing it in the function (or it is too large to make a copy). For example in `writefile`, `y, m, and d` are not modified so they don't need to be pointers.

Comment: And: [Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979217)

Comment: Let me suggest one thing you could say: "I have used a debugger and I observed that ..." (insert your observations).

Comment: And: `void income (float *ienakums) {... scanf("%f", &ienakums);...}` The variable `ienakums` is already a pointer. Don't pass the address of the pointer to `scanf`.

Comment: `d` and others are pointers and do not need `&` in `scanf`. Use `scanf("%d", d);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many issues in your code that need to be addressed:

1. **Never** use `gets()`. As already mentioned, it has been completely removed from the C standard. Use a combination of `fgets()`, `strcspn()` and `sscanf()` to read and parse your input.
2. **Avoid** using `scanf()` to read input too. It is very error-prone and shouldn't be used to read user input. Again, use `fgets()`, `strcspn()` and `sscanf()`.
3. `fflush(stdin)` is **undefined behaviour**. Just remove that line from your code.
4. When you open a file with `fopen()`, always check for its return value. It could be that the file couldn't be read normally or doesn't exist (if the mode is `"r"`).

---

To read one input line:

```c
char *readline(char *line, int size, FILE *stream)
{
    if (!fgets(line, size, stream)) // Check for errors
            return NULL;
        
    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
    return line;
}
```

---

To read an integer/float:

```c
int readint(int *i) // readfloat(float *f)
{
    char line[255];
    if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
            return 0;
        
    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
    
    return sscanf(line, "%d", i) == 1; // sscanf(line, "%f", f)
}
```

---

To check if your file has been correctly opened:

```c
FILE *file = fopen("dati.txt", "a+");

if (!file) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file\n");
    return 1;
}

fprintf(file, "\n\tVards:%s  Uzvards:%s  Dzimsanas Datums:%d %d %d Ienakums %.2f EUR \n", vards, uzvards, *d, *m, *y, *ienakums);
fclose(file);
```

Answer (score 2):

`&Name[20]` is the address of element 20 of the array. But there is no element 20, the array indexes go from `0` to `19`. So the function is writing past the end of the array.

You should just pass the array itself, not the address of a particular element.

```
name(Name, last);
```

When an array is used as a function argument, it's automatically converted to the address of the first element; you don't need an explicit `&`.

Also, don't use `gets()`. It's a dangerous, obsolete function that has been removed from the language because you can't tell it the size of the input buffer. Use `fgets()` and then remove the newline at the end. See [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Comment: I've implemented your changes and the program now proceeds to write a file. The variables for d,m,y and ienakums print  properly in the cmd window. However, in the resulting file I get absolute junk(random numbers) for d,y,m and 0.00 for the ienakums float. What could cause that?

Comment: In your `date()` function, `d`, `y`, and `m` are passed as pointers, but when using `scanf()` you're passing the address of the pointers (a pointer to a pointer). Since they're already pointers, you don't need the address, just use `scanf("%d", d)`. Similar problem for your `income()` function.

Comment: I made your suggested edit, yet it still yields these values(see image and changed code in the main post). Sorry for bothering you so much... just having a slow day :)